# ReactDOM is not defined ( but from within a React method )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touchstone.io

I'm very clearly loading and using React up until the point where it can't find it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Container from 'react-container';
import { UI } from 'touchstonejs';
import VoteContainer from '../components/vote-container.js';
import Solution from '../components/solution.js';
import moment from 'moment';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  addSolution () {
    var solution = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.solution).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
                     ^~~~ ReactDOM is not defined
```

But! Once I run `addSolution` , then React and ReactDOM are inaccessible. How does this variable suddenly get lost? What might I be doing to lose it?

This is the button that would call it within this class' render method..

```
<UI.Button type="primary" onTap={this.addSolution} >
  Send
</UI.Button>
```

Comment: ReactDOM is a separate package, you have to add `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`

Comment: @Mijamo Great point actually. I was forgetting to add it. But then I did and it still returns the same error.

Comment: I know it might sound obvious and I see you are importing react-dom correctly but did you install both packages ? `npm install react react-dom` ?

Comment: No question is a dumb question! :D I do have react-dom installed and included in my `package.json`. It's also a directory under `node_modules/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`v0.14`](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#installation), `ReactDOM` got separated to another package and given that `findDOMNode` is part of `ReactDOM`, in order to use it within your components you have to include it. For example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

/* ... */

module.exports = React.createClass({
  addSolution: function() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(...)
  }
})
```

Comment: Right, I understand that version situation. But even if I include those two imports it still doesn't work. In fact, I have it working in a separate almost identical file. So not really sure why this is going on like this

Comment: Hmm.. weird. Are you still getting the same error about `ReactDOM` being undefined? Could you do a `ls node_modules/ | grep react` and paste the result here? Maybe something's wrong with your modules...

Comment: What returns is `react
react-addons-css-transition-group
react-container
react-dom
react-sentry
react-tappable
react-timers`

Comment: Looks good. Next step would be to see if your build is compiled correctly after you imported `ReactDOM` in your component. Are you still getting the `ReactDOM is not defined error`? Also could you post React, ReactDOM versions? Sorry if my suggestions/questions look pretty basic/obvious but I'm trying to figure out possible causes for your case.

Comment: No worries my friend! Can't thank you enough for the help. :D `React v0.14.8` `ReactDOM v0.14.8` I'll update my answer above to have the complete class ( truncated ). Also, build compiles with no errors.

Comment: Tnx. Can you also check the compiled code for this component and paste it to a gist or something similar? I'm curious to see how it looks like.

Comment: Sure, here's a gist https://gist.github.com/gotoAndBliss/827c1ea531db61f6b38f3acdffcccea6

Comment: Looks OK. The problem might be someplace else. Could you try one more thing? Update your code to look like this: `<UI.Button type="primary" onTap={this.addSolution.bind(this)}>`. Could you also paste the error from the console?

Comment: I was thinking that too. React responds accordingly `react.js:20233 Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See exports`

Comment: I ultimately got it. Thanks in part to your help. Strangely enough, ReactDOM was accessible, but not if I put a debugger in console. Then I just had to rewrite how I was using it to get at my new target input elements.